# У непрочитанных уведомлений неправильный размер ссылки

Tags: дефект, дизайн, уведомления

У непрочитанных уведомлений есть жирные отступы, которые не являются ссылкой, но подсвечиваются как часть уведомления (к тому же, это пространство вообще некликабельно):

> [image: скриншот неправильного контекстного меню]

Соответственно, нужный мне пункт для открытия в новой вкладке там не показывается, хотя если кликать более центральную часть, то всё хорошо:

> [image: скриншот правильного контекстного меню]

Надо сделать так, чтобы размеры подсвечиваемой области и ссылки совпадали.

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/335470/309650)

Comment: Но разве 7+7 пикселей - это так много? Кликабельная область намного больше.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, но ведь я ткнул не в неё. И подсветка показывает, что так тыкать можно. А на деле - нет.